# jquery if checkbox within parent div is checked then include php file?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

QUESTION UPDATED

pqq.php file:

I have a form like so:

```
<form>

{General form input here, i.e. name, address}
<php include 'form_general.php'; ?>


{Specific form input here, i.e. equipment type}
<php include 'infrastructure.php'; ?>


<div id="placeholder"></div>


<submit>

</form>
```

So in my infrastructure.php file I have the following checkboxes contained within a couple of parent divs like so:

infrastrucure.php file:

Plant Hire Category

```
 <div class="option_select"><p class="select">Plant Hire</p></div>

    <div class="option_underlay">

    <div class="align"><p class="header">Access Platforms</p>
                <div class="float_column3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group1" value="same">Option 
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group1" value="same">Option
                <br> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group1" value="same">Option
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group1" value="same">Option

    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
```

Travel Category

```
<div class="option_select"><p class="select">Travel</p></div>

    <div class="option_underlay">

    <div class="align"><p class="header">Planes</p>
                <div class="float_column3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group2" value="same">Option 
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group2" value="same">Option
                <br> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group2" value="same">Option
                <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group2" value="same">Option

    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
```

JQUERY in my pqq.php file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=option]').change(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('group1')) {
            $('#placeholder').load("safety.php");
        } else if($(this).hasClass('group2')) {
            $('#placeholder').load("travel.php");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

what I am trying to do is if a user checks any checkbox from the Plant Hire category then it includes my safety.php file in the form. Otherwise if a user selects any checkbox from my travel category then my travel.php file is included in the form?

Does anyone know a way I can do this using jquery or other methods?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you use firebug or anything similar? It should show you, what's wrong.

Comment: I use chrome, I'm not sure what firebug is?

Comment: Have you included jquery library in your code mate..??

Comment: It's a debug console. In chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+J, reload the page and click the checkbox. It should write some output to the console. You may need to switch to the Network tab in console.

Comment: I recommend you to use Firebug Lite, it's better than the built in console. http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin thanks I got it, it was producing a 404 error, I just had to amend the url to my safety file and it works. thanks!

Comment: I thought it is most likely to be the problem :) I'm glad I could help

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin just a quick question I have noticed that if a user checks a checkbox the php file will show, however if the user unchecks the checkbox the php file still shows, but I want the php file to disappear in the event the user changes their mind and unchecks the checkbox, can this be achieved using an on check function and if so how would I do this? Thanks

Comment: in the change function you need to find if any checkbox from the group is checked, something like $('.group1:checked').length - this will return the number of checked checkboxes with class group1. Then do something like if(!$('.group1:checked').length) { $('#placeholder').html(''); }

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin im sorry but do you think you could right this in an example code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make div, where the loaded php file will be stored, in my code it would be `<div id="placeholder"></div>`, then for each group of checkboxes use the same class, in my code it's class `group-1` and class `group-2`. Then use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=option]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('group1')) {
            var length = $('.group1:checked').length;
            if (length) {
                $('#placeholder').load("safety.php");
            } else {
                $('#placeholder').html("");
            }
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('group2')) {
            var length = $('.group2:checked').length;
            if (length) {
                $('#placeholder').load("travel.php");
            } else {
                $('#placeholder').html("");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Can more checkboxes be selected? Or only one? If only one, you should probably uncheck all other checkboxes in the code.

Also you have in your sample code multiple same IDs, which is not a good practice.

Comment: @all checkboxes may be selected

Comment: Then you need to use different placeholder for each php file and check if any of checkboxes of the same group is checked.

Comment: ok thanks I will do, however when I just select 1 checkbox from group-1 my safety.php file is not being included. :/

Comment: Did you change the code anyhow or it is not working with my code? 'Cause I'm really sure that there is no error in my code...

Comment: The only thing I have changed is the class from 'group-1' to 'group1' but I have made sure that both the div class and the jquery match the same class :/